# bash autocomplete behaving strangely after update

Tags: bash, auto-completion

Since bash was updated very recently, when I try to autocomplete by tabbing during a cd I get the following...

```
tony@tony-HP:~$ cd Mucword=1
words[0]=${!ref}${COMP_WORDS[i]}
words[1]=${!ref}${COMP_WORDS[i]}
cword=1
words=("${@:3:2}")
cword="$3"
cur="$3"
cur="$3"
cword="$3"
prev="$3"
words=("${@:3:2}")
 compgen -d -- "$quoted" 
sic/
```

Here I've typed `cd Mu` at the prompt and tabbed and, after bash vomits the information I don't require adds `sic/` after identifying my Music directory.  What's changed?  Is there a setting that has been defaulted otherwise following the security problems?

p.s. Hitting return changes directory as you'd expect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know the question is a bit old but I will answer in case someone has the same problem. This can be fixed by typing 'bash +v' in a terminal. You probably typed 'bash -v' trying to see the bash version (like I did) but this does something else instead. 
P.S. to see the bash version use 'bash --version'

Answer (score 3):

Well, that answer is now also a bit old. However, it helped me, but it's also wrong. That said, it lead me to the solution, so thanks, Babis.

Running bash +v starts a new shell on top of the old one.

If you want to modify the behavior of your current shell, use the "set" command:

```
set +v
```

This tells bash to turn off printing input lines as they are read, the source in this case being the bash completion functions.

Amusingly, I ran into this in cygwin.